# VBA Macro to Return Consecutive Month-ends

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first ever post on this website.

I need help on some VBA code that will put 31/07/00 into cell “B2” and then each month-end date down the column and stop at 31/11/2010 in cell “B126” (ie. cell B2 = 31/07/00, BA3 = 31/08/00, B4 = 30/09/00 etc etc). Should I do a loop for this? I can’t really do it with the macro recorder which is how I am learning most of my VBA coding.

Thanks everyone for your assistance.

Answer (score 5):

```
Sub FillDates()

    With Sheet1.Range("B2")
        .Value = DateSerial(2000, 7, 31)
        .AutoFill .Resize(125, 1), xlFillMonths
    End With

End Sub
```

This puts the first date in B2, then uses Excel's Autofill (the fill handle from Joel's answer) to fill the months down in the next 125 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a macro to do it? Excel's autofill is pretty smart.

- Put 31/7/00 into B2
- Put 31/8/00 into B3
- Select both cells
- Grab the fill handle (the tiny square in the bottom right of the selection)
- Drag it down as far as you need

Comment: I need this as a macro because I have some additional code before and after it as well.

Comment: @Carole, you could record these steps as a macro.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub EndOfMonths()

    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    '
    Set StartCell = Range("B2")
    StartCell.Value = DateSerial(2000, 7, 31)
    '

    Do
        n = n + 1
        StartCell.Offset(n, 0).Value = CDate(eomonth(StartCell, n))

    Loop While StartCell.Offset(n, 0).Value < DateSerial(2010, 11, 30)
    '
End Sub
```

If using Excel 2003, go to Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11) Menu: Extras->Reference and select the "atpvbaen.xls".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am running Excel 2010 with both Analysis Toolpak addins enabled but I am still getting a compile error on "EoMonth" when I debug/run this code. What should I do?

Comment: Try using: CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(StartCell, n))
 instead of CDate(eomonth(StartCell, n))

Comment: Nice to hear that! please dont forget to mark this post as solved.