# VBA Macro to Return Consecutive Month-ends, preferably without looping

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a repetitive process using VBA. As part of the process, I need to fill a range of cells in an Excel worksheet with consecutive month-ends for a number of months previously calculated in the code.

I tried a solution presented by Dick Kusleika in this thread:
[VBA Macro to Return Consecutive Month-ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424929/vba-macro-to-return-consecutive-month-ends/4430440#4430440) which looked quite elegent and simple, and did not involve looping through every cell to be populated with dates.  Unfortunately, it produced a compile error.

This is the code I tried:

```
Dim xData As Worksheet
Dim xDLastRow As Long, xDProjCol As Long
Dim xSYear As Long, xMonths As Long

'Code that defines my variables and does other stuff

    With xData.Range(Cells(xDLastRow + 1, xDProjCol + 2))
        .Value = DateSerial(xSYear, 1, 31)
        .AutoFill.Resize(xMonths, 1), xlFillMonths  'ERROR HERE
    End With

'Other code...
```

On the Autofill.Resize line of code I get "Compile error: Expected: ="

My preference would be to find a non-looping solution, as this is already part of a larger loop and will be run multiple times.  If there is a quick autofill solution that would be ideal.

EDIT:
The corrections proposed by [Ahmed Abdelhameed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4934172/ahmed-abdelhameed) enabled the code to work.
The revised code is:

```
Dim xData As Worksheet
Dim xDLastRow As Long, xDProjCol As Long
Dim xSYear As Long, xMonths As Long

'Code that defines my variables and does other stuff

    With xData.Cells(xDLastRow + 1, xDProjCol + 2)     'REMOVED .Range(
        .Value = DateSerial(xSYear, 1, 31)
        .AutoFill .Resize(xMonths, 1), xlFillMonths    'ADDED SPACE BEFORE .Resize
    End With

'Other code...
```

Comment: There should be a space between `.AutoFill` and `.Resize` because `Resize` is a member of `Range`, not part of whatever `AutoFill` returns. Also, `.Range(Cells(...))` is not correct; you should use `xData.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex)` instead.

Comment: Thank you, Ahmed!

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the range with the EOMONTH function and revert the formula results to their value.

```
With xData.Cells(xDLastRow + 1, xDProjCol + 2).Resize(xMonths, 1)
    .Formula = "=eomonth(date(" & xSYear & ", 1, 1), row(1:1)-1)"
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy_)"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like a good alternative solution.  The corrections proposed by Ahmed Abdelhameed worked with my original code.